# Available Time Slots From a Ext.data.Store?

Tags: javascript, extjs

I am new to JavaScript and Sencha but familiar with as3/flex.  I built something similar to this in as3 but I am having a hard time moving this over to Sencha JS.
I have an Ext.data.Store.  This Ext.data.Store will change depending on the scheduled blocks of time for the selected date.  I need to be able to extract available 2 hour blocks of time based on these parameters.

The start time and end time is in 15 minute increments and should always be 2 hours in length.  Although some of the scheduled times in the Ext.data.Store may be greater than 2 hours, or less I still need to be able to display 2 hour time slots as free time. It is possible in the Ext.data.Store to see duplicate time slots filled because there is more than one person in the schedule.  I was thinking of setting some sort of loop by employee, so if the employee count was 3 it would loop through the code 3 times to find the available 2 hour time slots.

I am able to see the objects
Object
employee: "james"
endtime: "10:00"
stime: "8:00"
    **proto**: Object

but I don't know how to achieve sorting all the time slots by employee and then finding all two hour intervals between each employee's time slots.

```
Ext.onReady(function()
{
console.log('ready!');

var constants = {
'WORKDAY_START': '08:00',
'WORKDAY_END': '18:00',
'INTERVAL_HOUR_COUNT': 2
};
Ext.define('Times', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields:[
            {name: 'stime', type: 'string'},
            {name: 'endtime', type: 'string'},
            {name: 'employee', type: 'string'}
            ]
 })



 Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
 storeId: 'ac',
 model: 'Times',
 data : [
     {stime:"8:00", endtime:"10:00", employee:"james"},              
     {stime:"13:00", endtime:"15:00", employee:"james"},
     {stime:"15:00", endtime:"17:30", employee:"james"},
     {stime:"12:00", endtime:"14:00", employee:"carl"},               
     {stime:"14:00", endtime:"16:00", employee:"carl"},
     {stime:"14:00", endtime:"16:00", employee:"jimmy"}
 ]
 });



 function addZero(num) {
            // Create an array, if string is in "xx:xx" format, the array       will be ["xx", "xx"], otherwise it will be ["xx"]
            var i = new Number();
            var arr = String(num).indexOf(":") == -1 ? [num] :   String(num).split(":");
            for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) // Add an "0" if the string   is only one character
            if (arr.length == 1){
             arr[i] = "0" + arr[i];
                }
            return arr.join(":");
        }







 var ac = Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('ac').data;

 var employeeTimeSlots = new Array();
 ac.each(function(item, index, allItems) {

//console.log("a[" +arrayItem+ "] = " + index);
console.info(item.data);

//console.log('@ready');    
            var timeSlot = new Array();

            for (timeSlot in item.data) {

                  var employeeSlots = new Array();
                var employee = timeSlot.employee;
                if (!employeeSlots['employee'])   employeeSlots['employee'] = [];
                employeeSlots.push(['employee'],{
                    stime: timeSlot.stime,
                    endtime: timeSlot.endtime

                });
                //console.log(employeeSlots)
                //console.log(timeSlot);
            }

// Second step, find all two hour intervals between each employee's time slot

            /*for (var employee in employeeSlots) {
                var   employeeTimeSlots=Array(employeeSlots['employee']);
                // Add in the first and last time stamps
                employeeTimeSlots.unshift({endtime:   constants.WORKDAY_START});
                employeeTimeSlots.push({starttime: constants.WORKDAY_END});
                // Find all the time differences
                for (var i = 0; i < employeeTimeSlots.length-1; i++) {
                    // The end hours of the current time slot


                    var endDate = new Date(0, 0, 0,   employeeTimeSlots[i].endtime.substring(0, 2),
                        employeeTimeSlots[i].endtime.substring(3, 2), 0, 0);
                    // The beginning hours of the next time slot
                    var nextStartDate = new Date(0, 0, 0, employeeTimeSlots[i+1].starttime.substring(0, 2),
                        employeeTimeSlots[i+1].starttime.substring(3, 2), 0, 0);
                    // The hours in between the time slots
                    var availableHours = Number((nextStartDate.getTime() - endDate.getTime())) / (1000 * 60 * 60);
                    // For every two hours that are available between these time slots
                    for (var hourInterval = 0; availableHours -   hourInterval >= constants.INTERVAL_HOUR_COUNT; hourInterval += constants.INTERVAL_HOUR_COUNT)   {
                        // Trace the available time slot
                        trace(employeeName, "=", addZero((endDate.hours + hourInterval) + ":" + endDate.minutes), 
                            "to", addZero((endDate.hours + hourInterval + constants.INTERVAL_HOUR_COUNT) + ":" + endDate.minutes));
                    }

            }
                    }*/




 });
```

Comment: So what is your question?

Answer (score 0):

You can sort a store by a field or by  multiple fields.

If your store is named mystore you will have

```
mystore.sort('employee','ASC')
```

From documentation we have:

```
//sort by a single field
myStore.sort('myField', 'DESC');

//sorting by multiple fields
myStore.sort([
{
    property : 'age',
    direction: 'ASC'
    },
    {
        property : 'name',
        direction: 'DESC'
    }
]);
```